# Timestamps E+12? (PHP, SQL)

Tags: php, sql, database, timestamp

I'm trying to figure out what causes the following, but I just DON'T get it..

I want to update a timestamp in the database. So, I'll do this:

`$time = round(microtime(true) * 1000);`

`UPDATE table SET time = '".$time."'`

This worked perfectly! I had a timestamp stored in the database like this:

`1497099703644`

I left this personal project behind because I had a more important paid project But since a few days I'm back on this project again. And immediately I noticed that the timestamps were stored different. Like this:

`1.50732853038E+12`

Same code, different output..
I noticed this because some other code stopped working because of this.
But I quickly noticed that if I do `+0`:

`$time = round(microtime(true) * 1000);`

`UPDATE table SET time = '".$time."' + 0`

the timestamps will be stored normal like:

`1507330499030`

Is there anyone that can explain how this happens? I don't know why, but I think it happens since the timestamps starts with 15 instead of 14. Could this be true?

-

**EDIT:** 
I just noticed the same problem occurs when I just echo

`echo round(microtime(true) * 1000);`

Comment: if you want the current time stamp in seconds why don't you use `time()` function instead of `microtime()`? it is guaranteed to return an integer.

Comment: If i want a timestamp with seconds, I would have used that. But I want microseconds because it this application is a time based game. Anyway, your answer does not answer my question why this happens ;)

Comment: What’s your schema? Anything else changed?

Comment: @ishegg What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Post the table schema.